# Tengo problemas al intentar cambiar el tamaño de una imagen en css

Tags: css

No se porqué al modificar el alto y el ancho la imagen sigue igual, *¿alguien sabe cómo arreglarlo y/o cuál es el problema?*; y también, *¿es necesario usar JavaScript para hacer una web application o puede ser también Java?*

Mi código:

```css
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
}

li {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 0px, 13px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#logo {
  color: #FCA311;
  font-family: "Amatic SC", cursive;
  font-size: 80px;
  padding: 0px 50px;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
}

li {
  color: #14213D;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 16px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#welcome {
    font-family: "Indie Flower";
    font-size: 32px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    color: #003333;
    weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: dimgrey;
}

#music {
    height: 100px;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>G.G</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC|Indie+Flower" rel="stylesheet">
        <link type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li>Tracks</li>
            
            <li id="logo">Music</li>
            
            <li>Albums</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
        
        <h1 id="welcome">gg</h1>
        
        <div id="music">
        <img src="C:\Users\Luis Alberto Ramirez\Pictures\music9.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu imagen no tiene ningún `id` o `class`
, Por ejemplo si le pongo una clase:

```
<img class="logo-imagen" src="ruta/a/imagen.jpg"/>
```

y luego a esa clase le doy css:

```
.logo-imagen {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
}
```

Ahora si deberia funcionar